# Std_logic_vector to unsigned conversion problem

Tags: signal, vhdl, conversion

```
architecture behavioral of test is
signal lfsr_state : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0); 
begin        
LFSR_32_1 : entity work.setState port map(clk, lfsr_state);
process (clk)
begin
if (rising_edge(clk)) then    
    if((unsigned(lfsr_state)) <= 2147483648) then
            Bit_out <= '1';
        else
            Bit_out <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end architecture;
```

Hello, 
I have a problem concerning the conversion of a 32 bit logic_vector to an unsigned signal. The function above always returns '0', although I expect '0' and '1' to be returned with equal probability since the pseudo-random numbers of the 32 bit lfsr are equally distributed in the interval [0, (2^32)-1].
Might it be possible that the range of ((unsigned(lfsr_state)) is not in the interval [0, (2^32)-1]?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly that 2147483648 is not representable as Integer in the simulation tool you are using. The danger is that, being outside the Integer range, it is representing -2147483648, and the comparison is being performed against that!

Express the number as `X"80000000"`  (a bit vector literal) or if necessary, `unsigned(X"80000000")`  and it should work.
This form is not limited to 32 bits!

16#80000000# is another numeric literal so may or may not work. There are differences between simulators in this area, and again between sim and synth sometimes.

I am quite disgusted if a simulator just lets this happen without warnings or range errors; note that some sims (Xilinx ISIM) have range checks that are by default turned off. Turn on and try again perhaps...